# why @inject method is not working on the live server

Tags: laravel-5, digital-ocean, inject, forge

I am developing a laravel 5 app. In my code I inject a class that I created in App/Utilities/class.php. On my homestead machine it's working fine, I pushed the files to a server hosted on Digital ocean using forge and everything worked perfectly until 3 days ago when I start getting Class not Found error.

Have you ever been in such an error ? 
How could you fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is a composer autoloading issue. Try this:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```